# How to Unit Test a Method that changes data in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Suppose I have a code like below

```
public boolean checkForecastIfCityRaining(String name){
    result = WeatherAPICallToSomeVendor(name)
    if(result = rain)return true; else return false;


}
```

How would I unit test if the result data will change depending 
on what the API vendor is providing?

Would i mock a fixed result of every scenario and then unit test 
it like so?

Comment: yes, mock dao and any external data, file system, network calls...your testing your logic.

Comment: your actual code seems to miss something. What do you do with the `result` variable ??

Comment: @davidxxx looks like a misprint. I think it should be `if (result) then return true; else return false;`

Comment: @Ivan I think too. I would like to be sure before expressing any thought.

Comment: Yeah sorry i meant result = rain or result != rain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UNIT test should really only test a single method at a time (Isolate other functionality that might be invoked by that method).  My current group might achieve that by writing our function like this:

```
public class WeatherCheck
{
    private ForecastService fs;
    public WeatherCheck(ForecastService fs)
    {
        forecastService = fs;
    }
    public boolean checkForecastIfCityRaining(String name){
        result = forecastService.weatherAPICallToSomeVendor(name)
        if(result = rain)return true; else return false;
}
```

This would allow us to pass a mock forecast service into the constructor.  Dependency Injection would be better, but we don't do that yet.

Note: We differentiate between a Unit test and an Integration test.  We still might write our Integration tests with Junit, but they have more of a tendency to go out and actually poke the service--this can give you advance warning of a failure.  So you might write an integration test for ForecastService that simply calls the weatherAPICallToSomeVendor method of ForecastService and ensures a non-error result (Perhaps no exceptions or doesn't return null...).

Comment: I do wonder if it would actually be "better" from an API perspective to inject the `ForecastService` into the method. Assuming that this method is exposed somewhere else along the way

Comment: Yes it would, I mentioned that in the answer but jumping to injection isn't always trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function needs to be rewritten as this:

```
public boolean checkForecastInCityCondition(String city, String condition){
    result = WeatherAPICallToSomeVendor(city)
    return result == condition;
}
```

Now you gain the advantage of exposing clients to care about arbitrary `conditions` and you can enhance with a new API as needed. From a testing perspective you can now safely write tests like this:

```
public void testRainingInLancaster() throws Exception{
            //your code here
}

public void testSnowInRedding() throws Exception{
           //your code here
}
```

And you can determine which pieces need to be mocked for testing.

Comment: In your example, there is a mismatch between the method's city variable and the "name" parameter passed to the WeatherAPICallToSomeVendor.

Comment: @DavidWolff fixed